# Is there an R package to perform topic coherence and evaluate Topic Models?

Tags: r, topic-modeling

In the following link:

[Topic Coherence To Evaluate Topic Models](http://qpleple.com/topic-coherence-to-evaluate-topic-models/)

describes the topic coherence approach to address the evaluation of Topic Models. Do you know any R packages able to perform this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the package topicdoc, read the basic [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicdoc/vignettes/basic_usage.html).

You use this after you have created a set of topicmodels with the topicmodel package.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer. Anyway, I used the function `coherence(dtm, TopicList[[1]])` but I obtained: `Error in coherence(dtm, TopicList[[1]]) :  could not find function "coherence"`

Comment: `coherence` is used inside the function `topic_coherence`. Though it is documented it is not directly available for use. If you want to you could use `topicdocs:::coherence` and use the function. Note the 3 : to access internal functions.

Comment: @phiver do you know if it is possible to use `coherence` in BTM? Do you have something to suggest?